# How to check if a variable's value is in an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I made register and login options in an empty html (not on a webpage) just to see if I could and how I could do it. Now I ran into a problem - I can register multiple usernames that have the same value (for example I can register "test username" as many times as I want to).
I want to know how I can check if the value that the user puts in to register has already been registered.
Here is my code :

HTML :

```
<!-- Login -->
<div class="login">
<label>Login</label>
<input type="text" id="login-username" class="textbox"  placeholder="Username"/>
<input type="password" id="login-password" class="textbox" placeholder="Password"/>
<button type="submit" onclick="login()">Login</button>
</div>

<!-- Register -->
<div class="register">
<label>Register</label>
<input type="text" id="register-username" class="textbox" placeholder="Username"/>
<input type="password" id="register-password" class="textbox" placeholder="Password"/>
<button type="submit" onclick="register()">Register</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript :

```
function login() {
if(document.getElementById("login-username").value == username1 && document.getElementById("login-password").value == password1) {
    alert("Hi " + username1 + " you are now logged in.");
} else if(document.getElementById("login-username").value == username2 && document.getElementById("login-password").value == password2) {
    alert("Hi " + username2 + " you are now logged in.");
} else {alert("Wrong username or password");}


function register() {
if (username1 == null && password1 == null) {
    localStorage.removeItem("username1");
    localStorage.setItem("username1", document.getElementById("register-username").value);
    localStorage.removeItem("password1");
    localStorage.setItem("password1", document.getElementById("register-password").value);
    alert("Hi, " + document.getElementById("register-username").value + " is now registered.");
    location.reload();
} else if (username2 == null && password2 == null) {
    localStorage.removeItem("username2");
    localStorage.setItem("username2", document.getElementById("register-username").value);
    localStorage.removeItem("password2");
    localStorage.setItem("password2", document.getElementById("register-password").value);
    alert("Hi, " + document.getElementById("register-username").value + " is now registered.");
    location.reload();
}

var username1 = localStorage.getItem("username1");
var username2 = localStorage.getItem("username2");

var usernameAlpha = [username1, username2]; //This is a list of all usernames 
//and it's what I want to look through when I'm checking if the value/username already exists


var password1 = localStorage.getItem("password1");
var password2 = localStorage.getItem("password2");
```

Comment: `array.indexOf(newValue) > -1`. `indexOf` will return `-1` for not found or index value of found element

Comment: Use `jQuery.inArray( username1, username2 );` for checking in jquery

Comment: You mention 'array', but don't use them. If you did, for instance `users = [{username:"bob", password:"secret"},{username:"lea", password:"alder@@n"}]` would give you an array of user objects with a username, password, and other properties if you like. Or make a users object where the username is a property: `users = {bob:{password="secret"}, lea:{ ... }};`. You can check if a user exists using `users.hasOwnProperty`, or add/overwrite a user using `users['bob'] = {password: "secr3t"};`. Just serialize users to Json and store in a single LocalStorage value, which is then your 'user database'.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function register(){
   var users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) || [];
   var username = document.getElementById("register-username").value;
   var password= document.getElementById("register-password").value;
   var toBeRegister= true;
   for(i=0;i<users.length;i++){
      if(users[i].username === username){
         toBeRegister = false
      }
   }
   if(toBeRegister){
      users.push({username:username,password:password})
      localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rajesh I was able to make it work and here is how :

I just used his method to check if the username that the user typed in was in usernameAlpha. If it was I displayed an alert message "Username taken" and if it was not I simply registered the user like normal.

Here is the code :

```
function register() {
if(usernameAlpha.indexOf(document.getElementById("register-username").value) > -1) {alert("Username taken")
    } else if (username1 == null && password1 == null && document.getElementById("register-username").value != "" && document.getElementById("register-password").value != "") {
    localStorage.removeItem("username1");
    localStorage.setItem("username1", document.getElementById("register-username").value);
    localStorage.removeItem("password1");
    localStorage.setItem("password1", document.getElementById("register-password").value);
    alert("Hi, " + document.getElementById("register-username").value + " is now registered.");
    location.reload();

    } else if (username2 == null && password2 == null && document.getElementById("register-username").value != "" && document.getElementById("register-password").value != "") {
    localStorage.removeItem("username2");
    localStorage.setItem("username2", document.getElementById("register-username").value);
    localStorage.removeItem("password2");
    localStorage.setItem("password2", document.getElementById("register-password").value);
    alert("Hi, " + document.getElementById("register-username").value + " is now registered.");
    location.reload();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention 'array', but don't use them well. You still have variables `username1` and `username2`, which means you have to copy a bunch of code (again) if you want to introduce `username3`. If you build an array of users, or an object where the username is the key/propertyname, then you can build a more dynamic user database.

You can save and load the entire object in a serialized way to and from localStorage.

Do note that although it's a fun exercise, localStorage is not a safe place for this, and storing passwords (either in plain text or encrypted) is not a good practice either.

Anyway, it could look something like this:

```js
var
  userDatabase = null;
  
function loadUserDatabase() {
  // Load the user database only if it wasn't loaded yet. This way, various functions can 
  // always call this function 'to be sure'.
  if (userDatabase === null)
    userDatabase = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userDatabase"));
}

function saveUserDatabase() {
  // Save the entire database back to local storage.
  localStorage.setItem("userDatabase", JSON.stringify(userDatabase));
}

function normalizeUsername(username) {
  // "Normalize" the username by converting different styles of writing to
  // a base form.
  // In this case, trim and convert to lowercase to effectively make user 
  // names case insensitive while still usings keys/properties.
  return username.trim().toLowerCase();
}

function findUser(username) {
  // Check if user database is loaded
  loadUserDatabase();

  // Find the user by username.
  username = normalizeUsername(username);
  if (userDatabase.hasOwnProperty(username)) {
    return userDatabase[username];
  }
  return false;
}

function isValidUsername(username) {
  // Implement any limits you want (or need) to impose here. 
  // A length check of, say <1000 would be a nice addition.
  return username != '';
}

function setUser(username, password) {
  loadUserDatabase();
  username = normalizeUsername(username);
  
  // Set/overwrite the user
  userDatabase[username] = {password: password};
  // Save the database to disk.  
  saveUserDatabase();
}

function login() {
  var username = document.getElementById("login-username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("login-password").value;
  
  if (user = findUser(username)) {
    if (user.password == password) {
      // There is a match, log in
      alert('login successful as user ' + username);
    } else {
      // Password incorrect
      alert('Invalid password for username ' + username);
    }
  } else {
    // User not found
    alert('User ' + username + ' not found');
  }
}

function register() {
  var username = document.getElementById("register-username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("register-password").value;
  
  if (!isValidUsername(username)) {
    alert('invalid username')
  } else if (user = findUser(username)) {
    alert('user ' + username + ' already exists');
  } else {
    setUser(username, password);
    alert('user ' + username + ' created');
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Login -->
<div class="login">
<label>Login</label>
<input type="text" id="login-username" class="textbox"  placeholder="Username"/>
<input type="password" id="login-password" class="textbox" placeholder="Password"/>
<button type="submit" onclick="login()">Login</button>
</div>

<!-- Register -->
<div class="register">
<label>Register</label>
<input type="text" id="register-username" class="textbox" placeholder="Username"/>
<input type="password" id="register-password" class="textbox" placeholder="Password"/>
<button type="submit" onclick="register()">Register</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use the toString method from `Object.prototype`.

```
if( Object.prototype.toString.call( Variable ) === '[object Array]' ) {
    alert( 'Array!' );
}
```